# Numpy array not being accepted by keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

```
print(x_train.shape)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=15, batch_size=10)
```

gives an output

```
(1020, 224, 224, 3, 5)
Error when checking target:expected conv3d_11 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (1020, 1)
```

One sample input is a numpy array of 5 images.
How should I change/pre-process my input to make it work?

Edit:

My Keras model is a single 3d Conv net for now.

```
input_shape = (224, 224, 3, 5)
model = Sequential([
Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 1), input_shape=input_shape, padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last')
])
```

Still getting the same error.
Also, dimension explanation: 
1020: no. of samples,
224x224x3: single image dimension,
5: number of images in a sample,

Comment: Seems `conv3d_11` is not your first layer. Maybe the tensor shape has been changed during forward propagation. Perhaps you can show us your whole Keras model

Comment: what kind of data is x_train? I guess you are trying to train with image data, so what should each dimension mean? 224, 224 are width and height with 3 channels. what do 5 and 1020 mean? I suggest reshaping your data to (5, 1020, 224, 224, 3)

Comment: show us the Model ..starting from model = Sequential() .. or something like that

Comment: Updated the question with all the asked information

Comment: Quick question: Are you reading the image or just passing a string(probably image name) to the first layer?

Comment: Reading the Image completely using cv2.imread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer below sample code to implement Conv3D

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv3D, MaxPooling3D, BatchNormalization
import numpy as np

input_shape=(224, 224, 3, 5)   

model = Sequential()
#C1
model.add(Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 1), strides=(1, 2, 2), padding='same',activation='relu',data_format= "channels_first", input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2),data_format= "channels_first", padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#C2
model.add(Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 1), strides=(1, 1, 1), padding='same',data_format= "channels_first",  activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2),data_format= "channels_first", padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#C3
model.add(Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 1), strides=(1, 1, 1), padding='same',data_format= "channels_first",  activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2), data_format= "channels_first", padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

opt_adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt_adam, metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv3d (Conv3D)              (None, 16, 224, 2, 3)     32272     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d (MaxPooling3D) (None, 16, 224, 1, 2)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 16, 224, 1, 2)     8         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_1 (Conv3D)            (None, 32, 224, 1, 2)     4640      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_1 (MaxPooling3 (None, 32, 224, 1, 1)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 32, 224, 1, 1)     4         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_2 (Conv3D)            (None, 64, 224, 1, 1)     18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_2 (MaxPooling3 (None, 64, 224, 1, 1)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 64, 224, 1, 1)     4         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 14336)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 14336)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 256)               3670272   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 514       
=================================================================
Total params: 3,726,210
Trainable params: 3,726,202
Non-trainable params: 8
```